# I can't get My BLDC (Brushless DC motor) to run

Tags: pi-3b+, hardware, raspberry-pi-os

**Goal**
Use Pulse Width Modulation (I think that is the standard approach) to control the speed of my BLDC.

I have tried so many things

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <softPwm.h>

int main() {
    uint32_t start;
    int dc;
    int iores = wiringPiSetupGpio();// init by BCM pin numbering
    if (iores == -1)
        return 1;

    softPwmCreate(13, 0, 255);

    start = millis();

    dc = 25;

    //while ((millis() - start) < 20000)
    //{
        //softPwmWrite(13, dc);  //  
        //delay(500);
        //softPwmWrite(18, 0);
        //delay(500);

        // debug:

    for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
        softPwmWrite(13, i);
        delay(500);        //}
    }

    softPwmWrite(13, 0);  // digitalWrite don't work then here
    delay(500);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the current state of my code.
It is a copy and paste from one of the articles I read.
My usual approach is to build a base line and grow from there.

I can currently use pwm to slowly increase and decrease the brightness of an led.
I understand the beginnings of how commandline with
`gpio`
works.
I can modify gpio mode and set values in the command line for pwm and binary output.
I can do the LED hello world with Digital write and pwmwrite,
but for some reason I just for the life of me can not get my motor to spin.

**MOTOR**: ReadyToSky RS2212-320KV —https://www.amazon.com/dp/B075DD16LK/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_i_YXAM97TXS8AN9C1WX9MH?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1

**ESC**: ReadyToSky 30A. —- https://a.co/d/hDVOBIf

**Battery**: LiPo 7.4V/1600mAh
**PI**: 3 b+

My black Wire from the Esc goes to a colored wire
My White Wire goes to a white wire

Question:

step 1: baseline - What am I missing in the code in a Hello World kind of way?

step 2: googling hasn't gotten me there I have tried a lot - What books can i read? Suggestions on educational resources
I am in love with this stuff and really want to understand it and soon i would like to be able to do this without libraries straight at the register, but one step at a time.

**UPDATE**

All my motor does is beep every second.

I have read that it needs to be calibrated, but I have not read how.

Comment: `White Wire goes to a white wire` is meaningless ... any wire could be any color ... your question is not about the Raspberry Pi until you get the wiring sorted out

Comment: that is a fair point... I dont know which is ground and power yet on the esc

so i use that pattern to keep it straight 

but your comment is a fair point

Comment: you provided almost zero information about what you are doing

Comment: I have tried multple  gpio pins

Comment: im not sure what to add 

i have the code

i have tried multiple pins

what more can i do to communicate more

i want to be as clear as i can i just dont know what to add im sorry

Comment: Im trying to run my bldc

Comment: show your post to one of your friends ... ask if they understand how you connected everything

Comment: that actually doesn't really work for me because i dont really know anyone who does this

im teaching myself while my family sleeps

Comment: I’m sorry I assumed people knew what a bldc was… I’m making the edits

Answer (score 0):

The salient point is you are using an ESC to control the motor.

You need to control the ESC.

You control the ESC as you would a servo.

Look up servo and ESC and Raspberry Pi.

I suggest you use [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) rather than wiringPi for servo/ESC control.

Comment: That actually i hope is helpful thanks. I didn’t realize servos and bldc have that in common and I already switched to pig pio

Comment: I suggest you experiment with the pigs s command.

Comment: You wrote pigs correct? If so, thank you. eventually I want to write without a library because that is always my preferred choice. I will experiment with the pig command. As an experiment can i control a servo/bldc/esc directly with Command line?

Comment: Yes, `pigs s 4 1500` from the command line will send 1500µs pulses at 50Hz to GPIO 4.  A servo connected to GPIO 4 will go to its centre position.

Comment: Thanks I already started reading pigs man Page it’s long